# How to convert Neural network model (.h5) file to spark RDD file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, h5py

I want to store the deep learning model data in spark environment as a RDD file and to load model from RDD file(either reverting the conversion) in Python. Can you give the possible way of doing it